# Handling the foreign keys in data entry

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, mysql-5.6, mysql-5.7, mysql-workbench

I have two tables (Order and equipment) and they should be linked together by the order No. the SQL script is as the following:

```
-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `rr`.`order`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `rr`.`order` (
  `Order_No.` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `Order_Type` CHAR(8) NOT NULL,
  `Equipment_Quantity` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Order_No.`))
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8
COMMENT = '\\n';

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `rr`.`equipment`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `rr`.`equipment` (
  `S_N` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `OrderNo.` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
   `V_N` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `LS_N` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `FK_EQ_Inspection_ID` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `FK_EQ_Reinspect_ID` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `FK_EQ_Scentencing_Notification_No` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `FK_EQ_Repair_ID` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`S_N`, `OrderNo.`, `FK_EQ_Scentencing_Notification_No`),
  INDEX `OrderNo._idx` (`OrderNo.` ASC) VISIBLE,
  INDEX `FK_EQ_Notification_No_idx` (`FK_EQ_Inspection_ID` ASC) VISIBLE,
  INDEX `FK_EQ_Confirmation No._idx` (`FK_EQ_Reinspect_ID` ASC) VISIBLE,
  INDEX `fk_equipment_scentencing1_idx` (`FK_EQ_Scentencing_Notification_No` ASC) VISIBLE,
  INDEX `FK_EQ_Repair_ID_idx` (`FK_EQ_Repair_ID` ASC) VISIBLE,
  CONSTRAINT `FK_EQ_Reinspect_ID`
    FOREIGN KEY (`FK_EQ_Reinspect_ID`)
    REFERENCES `rr`.`re-inspect` (`Reinspect_ID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `Inspection_ID`
    FOREIGN KEY (`FK_EQ_Inspection_ID`)
    REFERENCES `rr`.`inspection` (`Inspection_ID`),
  CONSTRAINT `OrderNo.`
    FOREIGN KEY (`OrderNo.`)
    REFERENCES `rr`.`order` (`Order_No.`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_EQ_Scentencing_Notification_No`
    FOREIGN KEY (`FK_EQ_Scentencing_Notification_No`)
    REFERENCES `rr`.`scentencing` (`Scentencing_Notification_No`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `FK_EQ_Repair_ID`
    FOREIGN KEY (`FK_EQ_Repair_ID`)
    REFERENCES `rr`.`repair` (`Repair_ID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8;

USE `rr`$$
CREATE
DEFINER=`root`@`localhost`
TRIGGER `rr`.`before_equipments_insert`
BEFORE INSERT ON `rr`.`equipment`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
 IF NEW.V_N = 1 THEN
     SET new.LS_N = 0;
 END IF;

END$$

USE `rr`$$
CREATE
DEFINER=`root`@`localhost`
TRIGGER `rr`.`before_equipments_UPDATE`
BEFORE UPDATE ON `rr`.`equipment`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
 IF NEW.V_N = 1 THEN
     SET new.LS_N = 0;
 END IF;

END$$
```

by checking the 'equipment' table, it includes 'Order_No.' as a foreign key from the 'Order' table in addition to other foreign keys from other different tables.

I entered the data of one row for the 'ORDER' table, I was expecting that the value of foreign key 'Order_No.' in the 'equipment' table would read automatically and that did not happen. so how to do that?

Also, when I enter row of data in the 'equipment' table, will I ignore the other foreign keys as they will be linked through their tables?

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to accomplish? Specifically this statement "enter the data of the ORDER, to reflect the value of the order_No. in the equipment table" is unclear. Can you please add more details on what your goal is? E.g. which table are you trying to insert data into?...and/or what do you expect the final result should look like?

Comment: Is it clear now?

Comment: Yes thank you. You're wondering why the foreign key didn't auto-generate when you inserted into your Order table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Foreign Keys don't automatically generate in the child referenced tables unless you use the [CASCADE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html) specifier in the declaration of the foreign key. See [Why foreign key doesn't update?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5292054/5059085) for more information on how to use CASCADE with foreign keys and alternative solutions.

Comment: What I understand using Cascade in the trigger update to automatically generate in the child reference cause the purpose of foreign key is only to show link between the tables, am I right? if it is right, so incase of applying cascading, when I want to enter data for table includes several foreign keys, How can I do this taking in consideration that cascading will fill the columns of foreign keys? Also, generally, if I insert a row in all tables in the project how will these tables understand that each row in each table are related to each as for example data for one case? Thanks